# SOAP V2 - Getting gift message 'To' & 'From' information from the sales order

Tags: api, soap

Is it possible to gain access to the 'To' and 'From' data for a gift message from a sales order?

I'm able to get the gift message, but this is semi useless without the 'To' & 'From'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is [now] a known issue. I ran into the same issue on Magento EE 1.13.1.0 and submitted a ticket to Magento EE support who provided a patch. I've been told the support policy/contract disallows distribution of the patch, but if you are an EE customer you can ask them for it.

The short story is that it's simply missing functionality. The fields need to be added to the `wsdl.xml` and `wsi.xml` in the `Mage_Sales` module, and `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api::info()` needs to be updated to output the from and to fields.

Obviously, if you are going to be coding this fix yourself, do so outside of app/code/core.

Hope that helps